# Python Guizero Module

Tags: python, macos, module

I've been trying to download the GUIZERO python module on my macbook but i get this error when i type (how im supposed to install it):

```
sudo pip3 install guizero
```

I get:

"The directory '/Users/mac/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/mac/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: guizero in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages"

Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT::

I think it's because I do not have tkinter installed however it said that would be installed with IDLE and python 3? How do I go on installing the tkinter module for python 3?

Comment: Are you logged in as the `mac` user?

Comment: The last line also suggests the package is already there: "Requirement already satisfied: guizero in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages"". Have you tried running python3.5 and importing it?

Comment: My user is not called mac anymore, its "Dema." When I opened the IDLE to run the program I get: 

"from guizero import App, warn, info, Waffle, MenuBar, Box, Text, TextBox, PushButton, ButtonGroup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'guizero' "

Comment: And is the python version you're running 3.5?

Comment: Yea 3.6.1, I think it's because tkinter isn't installed but on the python website it said it would in installed with 3.6?

Comment: I asked "are you running 3.5" and you answer "yea 3.6.1". Perhaps there's a problem there?

Answer (score 0):

Do all of theses. Some may seem redundant but should get you there.

```
pip3 install guizero 
sudo pip3 install guizero
sudo apt install python3-tk
sudo apt-get install python-guizero
sudo pip3 install guizero[images]
sudo pip3 install guizero --upgrade
```